# Since 20.10, screenshots while in fullscreen games only shows desktop

Tags: games, screenshot, fullscreen, 20.10

Since I installed Groovy Gorilla earlier this month, I cannot take a screenshot of a fullscreen gaming session using keyboard PrintScreen button: it only shows the destkop (icons, sidebar, topbar) without wallpaper (replaced with transparent background).

I use the stock screenshot component (which is Gnome-screenshot, I guess).
It worked as expected prior to the upgrade.
I tested it in Kerbal Space Program and Civilization VI, both running natively (no Wine involved).

I have an NVidia 1660ti running with the latest drivers from nvidia, which got updated along with the system.

Is this a known bug? I couldn't find anything alike...
Can someone guide me in the process on finding out what's wrong and fix it?

Thanks a lot,

Xavier

Comment: I just realized I wrote I "installed" 20.10. That's not true: I upgraded it from 20.04.